# In book of Revelation is the fifth angel the first angel to sound his trumpet?

Tags: revelation

In Revelation 8:6 we read,

> Then the seven angels who had the seven trumpets prepared to sound them.

The first angel sounded his trumpet, and after this in v.7 we read,

> A third of the earth was burned up, a third of the trees were burned up and **all the green grass was burned up**.

In 9:3-4, after the fifth angel has sounded his trumpet we read,

> And out of the smoke locusts came down upon the earth and were given power like that of scorpions of the earth. **They were told not to harm the grass** of the earth or any plant or tree, but only those people who did not have the seal of God on their foreheads.

When the first angel sounded his trumpet a third of the trees were burned up and all the green grass was burned up, and when the fifth angel sounded his trumpet the locusts were ordered not to harm the grass, etc.

Did the grass, trees and plants grow again between the sounding of the first and fifth trumpets? Or, was the fifth trumpet the first trumpet to be sounded.

Comment: Only a third was destroyed.  So when the fifth angel sounded his trumpet the locusts would not be permitted to touch what survived.

Comment: @Sarah,when i read your comment it appeared that you had answered my question, but if you read the first angel you will find that all the green grass was burned up.Now read the fifth angel and you will find that the locusts were ordered not to harm the GRASS.

Comment: [Grass grows back after being burned.](http://www.unce.unr.edu/publications/files/ho/other/fs9640.pdf)

Comment: @Sarah,Hmm! would you agree that the plants must have got burnt as well when the first trumpet was sounded?

Comment: In chapter 8, the Greek for "green grass" is ["chloros](http://www.eliyah.com/cgi-bin/strongs.cgi?file=greeklexicon&isindex=5515), [chortos"](http://www.eliyah.com/cgi-bin/strongs.cgi?file=greeklexicon&isindex=5528).  In chapter 9 the Greek is [chloros, chloros](http://www.eliyah.com/cgi-bin/strongs.cgi?file=greeklexicon&isindex=5515) (same twice). Perhaps that will help.

Comment: @Sarah,your help is appreciated.

Comment: Is "one third" spread out evenly across the earth? Or is it localised to a third part of the globe, as on one continent only?

Answer (score 2):

Avoiding doctrinal bias and sticking to the text, there seems only one answer.  The description is of angels blowing a trumpet with a resulting effect. The first blows a trumpet, something happens. The second, another things happens, etc.  They can't all be blowing at the same time, otherwise John would not be able to distinguish the listed effects for each. Indestibuishable chaos would occur from all the judgments combined, if they all sounded together. **Therefore the fifth angel to sound his trumpet is the fifth trumpet being sounded.**

How this is applied/interpreted under the main doctrinal frameworks is varied. One can believe they are all sounded together every day under a very symbolic view. One can also try and figure out a practical hyper literal futurist view in terms of their partial literal destructions, possibly all closely occurring. However regardless from what doctrinal position one takes, the text arrays them in sequence for the purposes of the vision itself.

Comment: ,I would agree that the text arrays the trumpets in sequence for the purpose of the vision itself.However we do not know in what sequence John saw the trumpets in his vision.We are told in the book of Acts that John was an "uneducated man" so there is good reason to believe that John received help when the book was compiled.Also the state of the trees, grass etc,from the first to fifth trumpet(in my view) cannot be over-looked when trying to establish the sequence of the trumpets.

Comment: ,I am of the same view that the angels cannot be blowing the trumpets all at same time.I do believe that a trumpet is sounded every 180 days or [exactly] every 6 months.

Answer (score 1):

The fifth trumpet of God sounded during operation Desert Storm when the oil wells were liter blaze They were demons released from their abyss with stings in their tails. Stung!

[Endtime Ministries | The Endtime Show
Revelation: The Seven Trumpets and When They Shall Sound
April 4, 2014](https://www.endtime.com/blog/revelation-seven-trumpets-shall-sound/)

> Five of the seven trumpets that signify the end of the age have come
> to pass. With only two left to occur, we must look to the Bible to
> understand what to expect. The Bible indicates in Revelation that
> seven trumpets will sound before the end of the age and the Second
> Coming of Jesus Christ. Five of the seven have already sounded as
> evidenced by critical moments in recent history, and a third world
> war, which is the triggering event of the sixth trumpet, may have
> already begun. Our understanding of Biblical prophecies and the events
> that have already come to pass, will guide us in what to expect when
> the final two trumpets sound.
>
> The First Two Trumpets In Revelation 8:7, John describes an
> apocalyptic vision. His vision explains the triggering event of the
> sounding of the first trumpet — hail and fire mixed with blood falling
> to the ground, and approximately 33% of all of the grass and trees in
> the known world destroyed.
>
> During World War I, large amounts of artillery shells and chemical
> agents were released on troops for the first time in history through
> modern warfare, killing over 8 million people. Soldiers on both sides
> burned vast tracts of land in order to eliminate any natural or
> man-made items that their enemies could use.
>
> Another war, World War II is also the event that was triggered by the
> sounding of the second trumpet. Looking to Revelation 8:8-9, the Bible
> explains that a third of the ships involved in the conflict that
> coincides with the activation of this trumpet will be destroyed.
> During World War II, approximately one third of the ships that
> participated in the conflict were sunk. In turn, the nuclear bomb
> deployed at Hiroshima resembled “something like a great mountain
> burning with fire,” a sight that was new on the world stage.
>
> The Third Trumpet In a podcast discussing the seven trumpets, Irvin
> Baxter told listeners of his understanding of the sounding of the
> third trumpet, which occurred during the nuclear disaster at
> Chernobyl. In Revelation 8:10-11, the prophet explains that the third
> trumpet will sound before a star, called Wormwood, will fall and
> affect a third of the waters.
>
> In 1995, God prompted Irvin to research the Chernobyl disaster that
> occurred in the Ukraine in 1986, whereupon he learned that “Chernobyl”
> means “Wormwood” in Russian. Furthermore, the nuclear radiation that
> emanated from the destroyed power plant contaminated more than 33
> percent of the water supply in Europe and Western Asia, killing
> thousands and affecting hundreds of thousands of other citizens with
> diseases caused by the radiation.
>
> The Fourth Event Revelation 8:12-13 explains that the fourth trumpet
> would sound before the length of the days become shortened, and the
> sun would not shine for a third of the day. Therefore, time will be
> shortened and our days around the world will be experienced
> differently. After the Berlin Wall fell in 1989, a “new world order”
> with a new age of globalization began to develop. President Ronald
> Reagan challenged Mikhail Gorbachev to “tear down this wall!” and 29
> months later the fourth trumpet sounded.
>
> The Fifth Instrument According to prophecy, the fifth trumpet will
> sound before a bottomless pit of fire causes a massive amount of smoke
> to block the light of the sun. During the Gulf War, Iraqi soldiers
> ignited over 700 oil wells around the deserts of Kuwait, which were
> some of the largest, underground wells of oil on the planet. From the
> seemingly bottomless hole in the ground, smoke entered the atmosphere
> and blocked sunlight for three months. With Suddam Hussein as their
> president, whose name means “Destroyer” or “Abaddon” in Hebrew as
> described in Revelation 9:11, Iraqi soldiers incited a battle with the
> United Nations in the Middle East, an area still under turmoil.
>
> The Sixth Trumpet This second-to-last trumpet will sound before a war
> is started near the Euphrates River. This waterway traverses Syria,
> Iraq, Turkey and Iran, which comprise the Middle East. Revelation
> 9:13-21 indicates that four angels will command an army of 200 million
> individuals.
>
> With a population of more than 1 billion people, China is able to
> field an army that consists of more than 200 million soldiers, and in
> addition, countries united under the Islamic faith have the ability to
> create an army of the same size. When a new world-dominating
> government is established under the Antichrist, an event coming very
> soon, we will be in the midst of a great war that will see the
> Abomination of Desolation and the Great Tribulation.
>
> The Final Trumpet The sounding of the seventh trumpet will be the most
> dynamic event out of all the trumpets prophesied in the Bible,
> affecting all human beings. It is at this last trumpet that Jesus
> Christ will send angels to rapture all saints for their eternal reward
> and pass his judgments on the fate of the earth’s inhabitants. This
> event also marks the end of human government and the establishment of
> the Kingdom of God, on earth, for the next one thousand years.
>
> At this time, the end time, all of what the Bible has prophesied will
> come to pass and prove the power of God’s will. To learn about what
> the Bible teaches and how to understand the end time, join us during
> our regular television and radio broadcasts. For more information
> about the seven trumpets, purchase your own copy of The 7 Trumpets DVD
> from our Understanding the Endtime Series.

Comment: It would be helpful to put everything that you copy/paste into a quote block so users can see that what you posted is from another source. Adding a link to that source is also proof that you are not plagiarizing.

Comment: Welcome to the BH forum! Incidentally, Chernobyl means “Wormwood” (*Artemisia vulgaris*) in Ukrainian according to an old Ukrainian dictionary. It's also posted as such on Wikipedia, which is not considered a scholarly source. Over the years, I've found that I have to double check everything I read regarding the scriptures.

Answer (score 1):

The OP spotted a good question. In the Book of Revelation, we encounter a fascinating contrast between two verses: Revelation 8:7 and Revelation 9:4. In the former, it states, "all the green grass was burned up", while the latter instructs the locusts not to harm the grass. This apparent contradiction requires reconciliation and thoughtful interpretation.

First, let's examine the context of Revelation 8:7-12. The calamity brought by the first four angels follows a pattern: one-third of various subjects are lost. However, the "green grass" seems to defy this pattern. Since grasses and trees grow together, how can two-third of the trees escape burning when all green grass was consumed?

Here is a possible resolution: Rev 9:4 does not explicitly mention that the grass is green. Therefore, we can infer that the "green grass" in Rev 8:7 refers specifically to newly grown grasses. These young shoots are not entirely burnt but rather wither - a sign of the earth vulnerability. Even resilient grasses that thrive in tough terrain struggle to survive amidst the hail and fire.

In summary, the distinction lies in the state of the grass: the fresh green grass in Rev 8:7 suffers complete destruction, while Rev 9:4 refers to the remaining grass, which barely survive with its deeper roots.

It reminds me of the following verses from Ezekiel 14:21-22 NIV

> 21 “For this is what the Sovereign Lord says: How much worse will it be when I send against Jerusalem my four dreadful judgments—sword and famine and wild beasts and plague—to kill its men and their animals!
>
> 22 **Yet there will be some survivors** ..........

Comment: I don't see any *fascinating* contrast between the two verses, other than that the earlier verse has the earth itself in its sights, whereas the latter has the men that don't have the seal of God on their foreheads targeted. The grass is immaterial, unimportant, when considering the true "foci" that was heralded by the two trumpet blasts. Consequently, I see no argument whatsoever for the 5th angel to be considered 1st to sound off. One other thing to consider here is that these trumpet blasts could be many seasons, years in fact, apart.

Answer (score 0):

Rev 8:7 The first angel sounded: And hail and fire followed, mingled with blood, and they were thrown to the earth. And a third of the trees were burned up, and **all green grass was burned up**.

Rev 9:4 They were commanded **not to harm the grass of the earth**, or any green thing, or any tree.

I agree, the command of Rev 9:4 would be meaningless if there were no green grass left.  As Mike observed, we have no business speculating about the order of events when John clearly differentiates them by "first", "second", "third", etc.  The last verse in Rev 8, v13, also gives us a clear sense of chronology: "Woe, woe, woe to the inhabitants of the earth, because of the remaining blasts of the trumpet of the three angels who are about to sound!"  The observation you made about the grass is one of several indications that some time passes between different events in Revelation.  Grass does not need more than a few weeks to grow after it has been scorched (try it in your garden!), so at least a few weeks passed between the first and fifth trumpet.  Whether we interpret this passing of time literally or figuratively is a different question.

Comment: ,yes that is correct that grass grows quickly,but when the first angel sounds his trumpet a third of the trees are also burnt.They can not have possibly grown between the first and fifth trumpet.NOTE,when the locusts appear at the fifth trumpet they are told not to harm any PLANT or TREE.

Comment: The word translated "grass" in Rev 8:7 (where the grass is destroyed) and Rev 9:4 (where the grass is not to be harmed) is the same: "chortos", meaning "grass", and is translated "grass" in the KJV, NKJV, NIV, NLT, ESV, NASB, ASV, and YLT.  Concerning the other plants, the first trumpet caused the destruction of only a third of other plants, and left plenty left to be destroyed by locusts.

Answer (score 0):

Often times when you read apparent contradictions in the bible, they are not contradictions. This is God's way of allowing "Close" is all you are getting on this subject.

Comment: Hi Ken, welcome and thanks for answering! What do you mean by "close"? Can't we resolve apparent contradictions by using reasoning skills? Thanks.